# How do I access the variable of a dynamic route in EmberJS

Tags: ember.js

I've done

```
ember g route auth
ember g route auth/pending
```

Which then gave me :

```
app/
  routes/
    auth/
      pending.js
    auth.js
```

and my router has

```
  this.route('auth', function() {
    this.route('pending', { path: '/pending/:steamid/:token'});
  });
```

Which everything is fine, when I visit

`http://localhost:4200/auth/pending/1/2`

The page loads, but how do I access `:steamid` and `:token` outside of the `model`.

I'd like to use it so that I can set values in my `session` service

Like:

```
import Ember from 'ember';

export default Ember.Route.extend({
  session: Ember.inject.service(),

  steamID: this.get(// Params Some How),
  token: this.get(// Params some How)

  thing(params) {
    this.get('session').set('tokenID', token),
    this.get('session').set('steamID', steamID)
  }
});
```

^^ Pseudo code to express what I'm trying to accomplish.

Answer (score 1):

While it's not in the website documentation, looking at the [source code](https://github.com/tildeio/router.js/blob/master/lib/router/transition.js) of the `Transition` object passed to some `Route` hooks (e.g. `afterModel` and `beforeModel`) it have a `params` property which contains the dynamic segment params.

So you can, for example:

```
import Ember from 'ember';

export default Ember.Route.extend({
    session: Ember.inject.service(),
    thing(params) {
        // Do some check and returns the result
    },
    beforeModel (transition) {
        if (!this.thing(transition.params)) {
            transition.abort();
            this.transitionTo('/login');
        }
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You can set them in your service from many different hooks:

```
import Ember from 'ember';

export default Ember.Route.extend({

  session: Ember.inject.service(),

  /* Access from beforeModel */
  beforeModel(transition) {
    this.get('session').setProperties({
      tokenID: transition.params.token,
      steamID: transition.params.steamid
    });
  },

  /* Access from model */
  model(params, transition) {
    this.get('session').setProperties({
      tokenID: params.token,
      steamID: params.steamid
    });
  }
});
```

If you ask me model hook is the best choice. Especially if you want your query params to refresh the model every time they change (see [guide](https://guides.emberjs.com/v2.5.0/routing/query-params/#toc_opting-into-a-full-transition)).